# I got no response from the Node.js Bloomberg API package (blpapi)

Tags: node.js, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm working on a Node.js project and I need to price some stocks with the Bloomberg API. I found out that there's an NPM package for this API, so I had it installed and started testing it according to https://github.com/bloomberg/blpapi-node but I'm getting no responses.

This is my code:

```
var blpapi = require('blpapi');

var bloombergPricing = function ()
{
    var session = new blpapi.Session({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8194 });

    session.on('SessionStarted', function(m) {
        console.log('bonjou');
    session.openService('//blp/mktdata', 1);

    });

    var securities = [
    { security: 'AAPL US Equity', correlation: 0, fields: ['LAST_TRADE'] },
    { security: 'GOOG US Equity', correlation: 1, fields: ['LAST_TRADE'] }
];

session.on('ServiceOpened', function(m) {
    console.log(session);
    if (m.correlations[0].value == service_id) {
        console.log(session);
        session.subscribe(securities);
    }
});

session.on('MarketDataEvents', function(m) {
    if (m.data.hasOwnProperty('LAST_TRADE')) {
        console.log(securities[m.correlations[0].value].security,
                    'LAST_TRADE', m.data.LAST_TRADE);
    }
});

}
```

Is this package still working? If not, how is it possible to call the Java Bloomberg API from Node.js?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? (Under Developer Console)

Comment: There's nothing in my Node console!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a session.start(); at the end of the function.  This will trigger off the connection.

edit to include code that works for me:

```
var blpapi = require('blpapi');

var bloombergPricing = function ()
{
    var session = new blpapi.Session({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 8194 });

    session.on('SessionStarted', function(m) {
    console.log('bonjou');
    session.openService('//blp/mktdata', 1);

    });

    var securities = [
    { security: 'AAPL US Equity', correlation: 0, fields: ['LAST_TRADE'] },
    { security: 'GOOG US Equity', correlation: 1, fields: ['LAST_TRADE'] }
    ];

    session.on('ServiceOpened', function(m) {
        console.log(session);
        if (m.correlations[0].value == 1) {
            console.log(session);
            session.subscribe(securities);
        }
    });

    session.on('MarketDataEvents', function(m) {

        if (m.data.hasOwnProperty('LAST_TRADE')) {
        console.log(securities[m.correlations[0].value].security,
                    'LAST_TRADE', m.data.LAST_TRADE);
        }
    });

    session.start();
}

bloombergPricing();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. After adding the session.start(); instruction, I'm getting this error:

13APR2017_12:08:59.730 9785:2984225600 ERROR blpapi_platformtransporttcp.cpp:671 blpapi.session.transporttcp.{1}.<127.0.0.1:8194> Connection failed

Comment: That sounds like there's no communication server running on the localhost on port 8194.  You'll need a bbcomm.exe (for DesktopAPI, or a ServerAPI) running.  If bbcomm isn't running you may need to trigger it off manually (via the Bloomberg menu in Start -> All Programs)

Comment: In fact, I didn't install anything. What should I do? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 32 bits.

Comment: If you have access to a Server API or BPIPE through your firm you can specify the IP address in the session constructor (you'll probably need to add BLPAPI authorization requests to your code to get an Identity object for this to work).
Otherwise if there's only Desktop API (the one included with the Bloomberg Terminal) at your firm then you'll need to run your code on the same machine.

Comment: I have no special access to any bloomberg server or terminal through my firm. In fact, I just need to check the price of a stock. The only thing that I have now is the blpapi package installed through NPM. Should I install a software or something like that in order to make it work? I'm on ubuntu!

Comment: At this time the only way of getting data into the BLPAPI is via a Bloomberg subscription (either the Terminal or their enterprise feeds).
The Terminal/Desktop API would be Windows only (as your app needs to be on the same box).  ServerAPI and BPIPE would allow you to run your code on any platform.